# Drawing none Circular gradient

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, radial-gradients

In HTML5 when we want to fill shape by radial gradient we use:

```
ctx.createRadialGradient(centerX1, centerY1, radius1, centerX2, centerY2, radius2);
```

but this fill shapes by circular radial gradient. How to fill it by elliptic radial gradient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform the canvas context before you draw the gradient ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/LY8AF/)):

```
var c = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var radgrad = ctx.createRadialGradient(100,100,20,100,100,50);
radgrad.addColorStop(0, '#A7D30C');  
radgrad.addColorStop(0.9, '#019F62');  
radgrad.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(1,159,98,0)');
ctx.scale(1,0.5);
ctx.fillStyle = radgrad;  
ctx.fillRect(50,50,150,150);
```